# What is in a mysql provider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, mysql-connector

I have been toiling with an issue with mysql connector on and off for the past 3 months using a workaround. I even filed a [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67183) recently. However, I have found multiple instances of mysql connector failing in situations of advanced linq use. Some dating back to 2009 ( 3 years ) and still unresolved. In almost every instance, the user switched connectors.

I am considering doing the same. However, I came across looking at where mysql connector exists inside of my project. From what I can tell, it is only an included `.dll` (mysql.data and mysql.data.entity). After that, it is referenced only in web.config.

The first reference to the connector is in the connection string, `providerName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"`.

The second reference is the definition of the provider

```
<system.data>
 <DbProviderFactories>
  <clear />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
    description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
    type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, mysql.data, Version=6.5.4.0,
          Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
 </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

The third is inside of the assemblies

```
<add assembly="mysql.data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
```

And the last is another assembly reference

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.5.4.0" newVersion="6.5.4.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Is this really the whole footprint of the connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is this really the whole footprint of the connector?`

Yes and no.

**Yes**

As far as the project which references the connector is concerned, this is the whole footprint. The only configuration that needs to be made is to have `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.Entity` added as references to the project. Usually these are inside of the `packages` folder, and are then copied into the `bin` folder once a reference has been added.

**No**

The connector has a lot of internal code going on. Because of where it is defined, the connector inherits from and extends on the `DbProviderFactory`. This extension involves many classes and sub classes which determine how the interaction to mysql is enacted. Because it is open source, the actual code can be downloaded from oracle.