# How to customize MySql Connector/net?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, mysql-connector

MySql Connector/Net is not working properly. The team working on bugs is only 3 people and they do not resolve complex issues. There are still unresolved issues from 2009. I want to customize their connector so that it works for my complex situation. How can I use a customized version in my project instead of theirs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1) Download**

In order to customize a version of oracle's mysql connector / net you are going to have to download the source code here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

**Step 2) Open**

Next, you are going to have to unzip the downloaded source files. The meat of the connector will be in two of the projects, `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.Entity` ( [What is in a mysql provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12886068/1026459) ).

**Step 3) Edit The Connector**

Make any edits to the classes you wish in order to fix your complex situation.

**Step 4) Remove the signature**

This step will make redistributing your edits undesirable, you may sign it and make the changes if you wish but for a local deployment it is unnecessary.

Inside of `MySql.Data.Entity`'s `AssemblyInfo.cs` comment out this line:

```
//[assembly: AssemblyKeyName("ConnectorNet")]
```

Inside of `MySql.Data`'s `AssemblyInfo.cs` make these changes:

```
//[assembly: AssemblyKeyName("ConnectorNet")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MySql.Data.Entity")]
```

**Step 5) Compile and Build In Order**

Build `MySql.Data` *first*. Once built, open `MySql.Data.Entity`. There will be a warning about not being able to find `MySql.Data`. Add the reference to the newly built `MySql.Data` inside of the `bin/Debug` folder. Build `MySql.Data.Entity` as `Release`.

**Step 6) Move the files**

Inside of the `bin/Release` folder of `MySql.Data.Entity` should be both `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.Entity`. Take each one and overwrite their counterparts in your project's `package` folder.

**Step 7) Update References in your project**

Inside of your project, go to the references area. Remove both `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.Entity`. Right click on `References`, click `Add Reference`, select the `Browse` tab, navigate to the package folder, and then add both `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.Entity` that you placed there in Step 6.

**Step 8) Modify `web.config`**

There will be several mentions of `MySql.Data` inside of `web.config`. Each one of them will have `PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d` which must be removed (from all of them).

**Step 9) Make it so**

Enjoy your customized connector!

Answer (score 2):

There is now a community-developed open-source .NET connection library for MySQL: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector.

It provides true async I/O (for high scalability) and [fixes many bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#bugs-present-in-connector-net-that-are-fixed-in-mysqlconnector) in Oracle's Connector/NET.

Comment: The final nail in the coffin for me was that the MySQL dbs did not support the type of transactions that MSSQL does. I needed to have more control over committing, rolling back, and locking mechanisms. This was all years ago though, although hopefully someone will find your post about open source useful in the future if they are using a mysql connector.